# How can I replicate the TikTok logo in Fontawesome (with colors)

Tags: css, icons, tiktok

The TikTok icon was added to FontAwesome last year (.fab .fa-tiktok), but of course, it's a flat color. I want to style it in CSS, to match the TikTok branding guidelines. That is the light blue and pink colors.

I've tried to create a solution using a filter: but it cuts out the original (black) lettering. Here's where I've got so far:

```css
.fab .fa-tiktok {
  color: #111111;
  filter: drop-shadow(-5px -5px 0 #24f6f0) contrast(150%) brightness(110%);
  z-index: -1;
}

.fab .fa-tiktok::after {
  filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 0 #F70250) contrast(150%) brightness(110%);
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iBBXm8fW90+nuLcSKlbmrPcLa0OT92xO1BIsZ+ywDWZCvqsWgccV3gFoRBv0z+8dLJgyAHIhR35VZc2oM/gI1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<i class="fab fa-tiktok fa-2x"></i>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [mix-blend-mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode) to multiply the colors. The problem is that the two official colors (cyan and magenta) do not add up to black, they need a yellow component which is absent. So I added some yellow to the magenta, bringing it close to red, but the overall result is almost identical to the official logo.

```css
.tiktoklogo {
  font-size: 100px;
  position: relative;
  color: #00fff8;
}
.tiktoklogo i:last-child {
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
  color: #ff0010;
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  top: 7px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" />

<div class="tiktoklogo">
  <i class="fab fa-tiktok"></i>
  <i class="fab fa-tiktok"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: Here you can find the hex codes of the actual colors the tiktok logo comprises of https://www.designpieces.com/palette/tiktok-color-palette-hex-and-rgb/

Answer (score 3):

Your css isn't even being applied appropriately because .fa-tiktok is not a children of .fab as your code describes it.

Regardless, add two drop-shadows to the content of .fa-tiktok with 2px marginal (negative for the blue, positive for the red).

```css
.fa-tiktok {
  color: #111111;
  
  filter: drop-shadow(2px 0px 0px #FD3E3E) drop-shadow(-2px -2px 0px #4DE8F4);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iBBXm8fW90+nuLcSKlbmrPcLa0OT92xO1BIsZ+ywDWZCvqsWgccV3gFoRBv0z+8dLJgyAHIhR35VZc2oM/gI1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<i class="fab fa-tiktok fa-2x"></i>
```

Comment: That's a nice approximation, but the black part is actually the intersection between two colored logos, not the logo itself.

Comment: @ariel, correct me if I'm wrong, but that should be possible to simulate by setting the top marginal for the red color to 0, I believe?

Comment: That's also an approximation. At this size should be difficult to notice. Check my answer to see the difference.

Answer (score 0):

check this i made 2 copies of it and positioned them with different colors

```css
.fab .fa-tiktok {
  color: #111111;
  filter: drop-shadow(-5px -5px 0 #24f6f0) contrast(150%) brightness(110%);
  z-index: -1;
  
}

.fab .fa-tiktok::after {
  filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 0 #F70250) contrast(150%) brightness(110%);
  z-index: -1;
}
i{
    position: absolute;
font-size:200px
}

i:nth-of-type(1){
    color: #E62259;
    right: 10px;

}


i:nth-of-type(2){
    color: #02F4EB;
    top: -2px;
    opacity: 0.7;
}
.container{
    position: relative;
    width: 40px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>index</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iBBXm8fW90+nuLcSKlbmrPcLa0OT92xO1BIsZ+ywDWZCvqsWgccV3gFoRBv0z+8dLJgyAHIhR35VZc2oM/gI1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" />

</head>
<div class ="container">
<i class="fab fa-tiktok fa-2x"></i>
<i class="fab fa-tiktok fa-2x"></i>
<i class="fab fa-tiktok fa-2x"></i>
</div>



<script src="test.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```